# Google Sheets Time tracking formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, duration, gs-vlookup

I'm trying to build a formula that looks across input data from one sheet (range C5:I52) and categorize it in another. It is a time tracking sheet. 
What I am trying to achieve is one sheet with input data, per 30 minutes, where I can put in for example Netflix from 22:00 to 23:00 in cell C49 & C50, and have in sheet2 Netflix added as a category under a value ranging from a dollar amount.

For example, Netflix would be a category under maybe $10 (not making traction to my goals - therefore a low value).

What I have tried is to create a LookUp formula with premade categories (e.g. for $10 maybe Netflix, and for $0 maybe Instagram, Snapchat, and other 'useless' activities) but I can't seem to get it to work. It would search how many times it can maybe find Snapchat in cells C5:I52 and then have that amount (let's say Netflix found 2 times - meaning 2 times 30 minutes - is 1 hour total) times $5, so if I would spend 1 hour a day on Netflix it would value my total activity for that week at $70.

The main things are to 1. search the amount of times a premade activities is found and 2. have that amount be a number (say if found 4 times it would be 30 minutes * 4 = 2 hours) and maybe have it 4 * $5 resulting in a $20 value for that category.

Hopefully, someone can help. The total value in dollar amount is a different column, on the right to the category. So let's say under column $10 it would say Snapchat in column D under $0, and column E is the amount of Hours in a dollar amount being Value. Then column F would be $10, column G value, etc.

The goal is to manually log time through an Input sheet, and have it valued automatically in an Output sheet.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Hi, here it is:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B6g2Yjl4FxeWmzmkq8ZEFlwKBNdBFgRnUk-0MAiEeAs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: the exact output is unknown pls edit your shared sheet and include example

Answer (score 1):

**this is how you get the duration of spent time for each category:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B5:B28, TEXT(SORTN(SORT({'Time Input'!C5:C52,
 MMULT(N(TRANSPOSE(IF((TRANSPOSE(ROW('Time Input'!C5:C52))>=
 ROW('Time Input'!C5:C52))*('Time Input'!C5:C52=TRANSPOSE('Time Input'!C5:C52)), 
 TIMEVALUE("00:30"), 0))), ROW('Time Input'!C5:C52)^0), 
 ROW('Time Input'!C5:C52)}, 3, 0), 49, 2, 1, 0), "[h]:mm"), 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

where time input sheet is:

[image: 0]

Comment: I've just created premade categories in Time Output row 39 - 62. Under the $ valued column (C5:C28, E5:E28, etc.) the category should be displayed (e.g. Netflix) and then next to it the value (amount of time calculation resulting in hours, rounded with .5 or rounded with ones). For time input, I have also now filled all week. 

Categories are now just standard categories, but will be changed later on. For example, the extreme $10,000 one could be a capital allocation decision. So for every $ amount there will be different categories.

Comment: Calculation of hours seem to work well now. But it does not display the category, it displays time in both cells. Any idea why and how to fix it? 
Thank you for the help so far, I really appreciate it.

Comment: see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B6g2Yjl4FxeWmzmkq8ZEFlwKBNdBFgRnUk-0MAiEeAs/edit#gid=551337160

Comment: If I try to paste that formula in cell C5 it gives an error. It's 1 formula that gets pasted in 1 cell and gets the Categories + Hours amount for one $ column right? I do not really understand the formula, but I am trying to.

Comment: It works pretty well now, but the thing missing is that it gathers all data for 1 date, and puts that under one $ category. But it should gather data for the whole week, look up what events are in what $ category, then add them accordingly.
I have just added different events for different $ categories, and did a random week with random events. Would it be possible that cell C5 has one formula which creates all the output for all $ values (even if one isn't there, it would just be empty, for example if no extreme $10,000 activities it just remains empty)
Thank you so much for the help so far!